# Finding a unique value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

Lets say I have two columns, A, B, and that the A column is in order from lowest to highest.

```
A     |      B
1     |      1.1
2     |      1.1
2     |      1.2
3     |      4.5
3     |      9.6
4     |      1.0
```

I am trying to sum up all of the values in column B that pertain to a specific value in column A. How can I do this the most efficiently? I know that the INDEX function can do this, but I do not want to manually find all of the different value groups, how large they are, and what rows they are at.

Comment: Pivot table perhaps?

Comment: -1 You write "I am trying to sum up all of the values in column B that pertain to a specific value in column A"  WHAT ON EARTH DOES THAT MEAN?  Try to make a new column that states TRUE or FALSE, for whether or not you want to sum it. And that does mean figuring out your rule and stating it. Like if A=1,2,3 and B=3,2,1 then do you count where A=1 as a number to sum. And are you disregarding the part after the dot in column B, so 9.9 in B would correspond to 9 in A?

Comment: For instance, in column A 1 appears once, and has an associated value of 1.1, therefore the sum would be 1.1; 2 appears twice, its first value is 1.1 second is 1.2, the sum would be 2.3; 3 appears twice, first value 4.5 second value 9.6, sum is 14.1. The question is how to do this calculation dynamically.

Comment: @raystafarian I looked at the pivot table, and I do not see how pivot tables can classify the different numbers in different rows.
I created a pivot table for the entire set; instead of it showing '1-1; 2-2.3' it shows '3-3.3'. I do not see how pivot tables can break the sum down into individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [pivot table](https://support.office.com/client/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)!

Highlight your table and go to Insert → pivot table and arrange it how you want. I'd do the following -

[image]

Comment: You might want to expand your answer to more than just a sentence. At least giving a minimal working example for the question asked would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You use SUMIF(range,criteria,sum_range), if you do not want to manually enter all of the possible criteria you can use in combination with a H or VLOOKUP(). This is my preference for something like this, easier to adjust and can format your output differently to a pivot table.
[SUMIF() Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx)